# Is there any connection between the choice of characters for 九 and 丸?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

I just learned the character 丸 and naturally noticed that it is similar to 九 with the additional 点.

Is there any interesting connection between these two characters or is it just a random coincidence ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

「九」 and 「丸」 are not related. As @user3306356 points out, 「丸」 is probably related to 「夗」.

---

<kbd>[商朝](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲骨文](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image: 九]
[菁](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.1
[合集6057](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6057&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金文](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 九]
作冊夨令簋
[集成4300](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4300&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
金文
[image: 九]
東周左壺
[集成9640](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9640&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[小篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image: 九]
[九部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77392&page=93)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 九]</kbd>

「九」 depicts an arm showing the hand, a bent wrist, and *elbow*, indicating the original meaning *elbow*. This word is now written as 「肘」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*t-[k]<r>uʔ/**).

The meaning *nine* (**/*[k]uʔ/**) for 「九」 is a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

---

「丸」 is derived from 「夗」.

「夗」 (**/*[ʔ]o[r]ʔ/**) was originally a *picture of an animal or person curled up in a foetal position*, extended to mean *twisting and turning in bed* and then *crooked, winding* (now written 「宛」).

「夗」 or its derivatives later started being used for different senses. 「丸」 (**/*[ɢ]ʷˤar/**) was corrupted from 「夗」 to specifically represent the sense *curl up and roll* > *ball, round object*.

The glyph evolution and corruption process is as follows:

<kbd>商朝
甲骨文
[image: 夗]
1799
殷虛文字乙</kbd>
<kbd>楷書
[image: 夗]</kbd>

<kbd>西周
金文
[image: ⿱夗口]
能匋尊
[集成5984](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5984&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定文字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image: ⿱夗口]</kbd>

<kbd>西周
金文
[image]
仲義父鼎
[集成2542](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2542&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>隸定文字
[image: ⿱宀⿱夗口]</kbd>

<kbd>小篆
[image: 丸]
[丸部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=56)
說文解字</kbd>

<kbd>[晉朝](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(266%E2%80%93420))
[篆刻](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_carving)
[image: 丸]
晉烏丸率善
篆刻大字典</kbd>

<kbd>今
楷書
[image: 丸]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [漢語多功能字庫](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)

Answer (score 4):

「丸」has more to do with「夗」than it does with「九」.

「丸」is a derivative character of「夗」.

Comment: These questions are difficult to demonstrate the answer to without pictures, aren't they :p

Comment: @dROOOze I'm sure you could write up a much better answer than this one.